# How resize and crop thumbnail image to a particular height and width in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

Presently I am doing a project in WordPress. It's a daily news update site.
My layout goes like this:

[image]

In the above Layout I set the images of posts by Featured Post Images and displayed by using the get_the_post_thumbnail(postid). While using this function my image getting stretched and distorted.

And I tried another way by passing size attribute to above function like medium and large, but no luck.

My question can we get two predefined like (830px/542px and 800px/330px) sizes of images at a time while uploading any size of image to a WordPress.

I tried some plugins that are available in WordPress, but there is no luck in that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size). Throw a couple of those in your theme functions.php file or a plugin you are creating for this. This will create an appropriately sized image for every image you upload in the admin. It will **not**, however, upscale an image. Thus this will only create an image of 830px/542px and 800px/330px if the source image is larger than that. This should be fine though.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
    use a plugin like the Ajax Thumbnail rebuilder. OR

    Go to your functions.php and look for this code

         add_image_size( 'properties', 280, 200, TRUE );

    280 is the width and 200 is the height in pixel.

    This should solve your problem
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know php, you can do custom stuff using the Image Editor
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor